# IS it possible to color dots using mosaic::dotPlot?

Tags: r

I am trying to show a dot plot and color the dots using the `d$color`. In the current solution setting `col = c("red","green")` is not dynamic. You can see the first point in the d$color should be green but it appears red. There should be 6 green dots and 4 red dots but there are 6 red and 4 green dots.

The data in the d vector will change all the time so hardcoding col = c("red","green")  won't allow for the accurate dot colors. Is there a way to just use col = d$color?

```
  library(mosaic)
n=10
r =c(seq(1,15,1))
binwidth = 1
dat = sample(r ,n= 1,size = n, replace = TRUE)
d = data.frame( x = dat, color = c(rep("red",n/2), rep("green",n/2)))
d$color[1] = "green"
d
dotPlot(~x,data=d, groups = color, breaks = seq(min(d$x)-binwidth,max(d$x)+binwidth,binwidth), cex = 1, col = c("red","green"))
```

Answer (score 4):

Since this is a lattice plot, you need to use "groups" as an argument when you want the separate items in the same panel, and 'col' needs to be a vector of the same length as the number of groups:

```
dotPlot(~x, groups=color,data=d, breaks = seq(min(d$x)-.1,max(d$x)+.1,.1), col=c("green","red"))
```

There will be an implicit "factor()"-ing of the d$color column and the order of the colors given to the col-argument needs to match the lexical ordering of the color column that will result so 'green' is first and 'red' is second. If you wanted to do that programmatically it would be `col=sort(unique(d$color))`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @BondedDust.  What if I had different colors for each dot? Can you take a look at the edited post? I have a d$color vector where I'd like to stores the colors for the dots. In my example half of them are red and half green but I am not seeing any green dots. I was thinking I could set col = d$color and then each dot would be colored according to its corresponding color in d$color. Is that possible

Comment: What was wrong with the answer given? It did color the red-labeled items differently than the green-labeled items.

Comment: Please run edited code. using col = c("red","green") can produce incorrect dot color because the data will change. The first do twill should not always be colored red.

Comment: The problem is with the order of vector given to the col argument. There will be an implicit "factor()"-ing of the d$color column and the order of the colors given to the col-argument needs to match the lexical ordering of the color column that will result so 'green' is 1 and 'red' is 2. (The ordering is not determined by the value in the first row.) I will change my code above since I wasn't really thinking about the order when I wrte the answer.